# How to play media file

Tags: android

I am using the following code to play audio file.
I have tested the audio file on Android phone player & its playing quite loud.
When I am trying to play the same audio file from the following code , its very feeble.
Is there any problem with my code ? Can I increase the volume of the media file by changing any value ?

While testing , the volume of the Android device has been put to maximum value.

Kindly provide your inputs/sample code.
Thanks in advance.

```
public void playAlertSound() {

        MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.beep);
        player.setLooping(false); // Set looping
        player.setVolume(0.90f, 0.90f);
        // Begin playing selected media
        player.start();
        // Release media instance to system
        player.release();

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `player.setVolume(1.0f, 1.0f);` instead; or just leave off that line entirely. You can also try scaling up the value past 1.0, although that's not really recommended.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't call `player.release()` immediately. Try calling that in your `onPause()` or `onDestroy()` methods instead.

You might try using [AudioManager.getStreamMaxVolume()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) to get the maximum volume and use it:

```
AudioManager audio =
    (AudioManager) Context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
int max = audio.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
player.setVolume(max, max);
```

I'm not sure though if `setVolume()` expects absolute levels or multipliers from `0.0f` to `1.0f`. It mentions logarithmic adjustment, so you might try something closer to 1.0f like `0.95f` or `1.0f` itself.

Comment: Thanks Matthew for your inputs , but is it possible to set the audio file to MAX volume by default ?